# How can we prove that these series are convegent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. How we can prove that these series are convegente:

1) $$S=\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{r^{m^2}}$$

2) $$D=\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{(p_{m}-2(m-1))}{r^{m^2}}$$

where $p_{m}$ is the $m$-th prime and we have $$2m≤p_{m}≤r^{m}$$ for all $m≥3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $\frac{1}{r^{m^2}}<\frac{1}{r^m}$ for $r>4$. Therefore $S=\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{r^{m^2}}<\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{r^{m}}=\frac{1}{r-1}$. Hence (1) is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

One way, requiring perhaps the least pencil-writing, is to show that both $S$ and $D$ are bounded above by

$$ \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{2^m}{4^m} = \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{1}{2^m} = 1$$